# Changing the color of \alert command in Beamer

Tags: beamer, color

Is it possible to change the color of `\alert` command in beamer. See, it is not the alertblock!
For example, I would like to change to color yellow, because the standard color is red, and my background is dark blue.

Comment: Please, have a look to the manual: 17.2.3 Setting Beamer’s Colors explains in detail such a task.

Comment: Note that it is fine to accept your own answer. You won't get any points but it will mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I found, the command is

```
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=yellow}
```

I was think this command changed only alertblocks.
I'm sorry by your time here. Thanks