# Beamer - stop page numbering

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I would like to stop the page numbering for some slides that are basically the same. Does anyone know how to do it?

I attach a (MWE) example below. As you can see in the first slide I highlight in red the title of column 1, in the second slide (identical to the previous one) I highlight column 2. Latex counts two slides, whereas I would like to count only the first.

```
\documentclass[10pt,notes=show,beamer]{beamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}


\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}

%%%%%%%%%%% BEAMER TEMPLATE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% END PREAMBLE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{First slide}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \textcolor{red}{Column 1} & Column 2  \\
        \hline \hline
        num1    & num2   \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second slide}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Column 1 & \textcolor{red}{Column 2}  \\
        \hline \hline
        num1    & num2   \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to be more clear, now latex counts a total of two pages and displays 1/2 and 2/2, whereas I would like to see 1/1 and 1/1

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}, \usepackage{graphicx} and \usepackage{color}` with beamer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is the command `\alert`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First slide}

    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \alert<1>{Column 1} & \alert<2>{Column 2}\\
            \hline \hline
            num1    & num2   \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly! I just have a follow-up question: what if I would like to highlight Column1/Column2 with a color that is not red? Can I still use the command \alert?

Comment: The color of `\alert` can be changed: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96864/changing-the-color-of-alert-command-in-beamer
However, if you want more flexibility, you should probably use `\textcolor` (see also @Skillmon's answer)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the commands `\only` and `\visible` added by beamer? Those might help you. If you really want to use two `frame` environments, you could decrease the counter by 1 or use the handy option `noframenumbering` (the latter might be preferred as it's the way `beamer` wants you to do it). The following uses both approaches:

```
\documentclass[10pt,notes=show,beamer]{beamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}


%%%%%%%%%%% BEAMER TEMPLATE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% END PREAMBLE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{First slide}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \textcolor{red}{Column 1} & Column 2  \\
        \hline \hline
        num1    & num2   \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

%\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}% possible alternative

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Second slide}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Column 1 & \textcolor{red}{Column 2}  \\
        \hline \hline
        num1    & num2   \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{combined}% >>>
  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \only<1>{\textcolor{red}}{Column 1}
        & \only<2>{\textcolor{red}}{Column 2}\\
      \hline\hline
      num1 & num2 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}% <<<


\end{document}
```

As @samcarter pointed out, `beamer` alters the command `\textcolor` to also support `\textcolor<1>{red}{Column 1}` and `\textcolor<2>{red}{Column 2}`. So instead of `\only<1>{\textcolor{red}}{Column 1}` one could also use that.

Comment: Maybe a bit easier: `\textcolor<2>{red}}{Column 2}`

Comment: @samcarter you even hacked `\textcolor`? I didn't know that, but I think showing the more basic commands like `\only` gives more opportunities, as one could add almost arbitrary stuff there.

Comment: I'm innocence! It's beamer who redefined many of the basic commands.

Comment: @samcarter I thought you were part of the team maintaining `beamer`. Sorry if that was wrong.

Comment: Instead of `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}` you could also use `noframenumbering` as option for the second frame.

Comment: @samcarter is there something `beamer` doesn't have a solution for?

Comment: It does not (yet) bring coffee to my desk.