# How to correct this syntax for using like \color<3-> with xcolor?

Tags: beamer, errors, color

I am using a set of slides in latex which I am going to change it to my needs. It contains 
 '''$\amat{
  1 1 2;
  0 \color<6->{red}1 {-1};
  0 \namedbox{b32}{1} 1}$''

, it has the following error

! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `<'.
See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.

Comment: Use the beamer-specific `\alert<3->{...}` and change the alert color. You can also use `\alt<3->{\color{red}}{\color{black}}`, say.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I don't understand. Could you please explain it a little, how to solve this error.

Comment: Well, there is no MWE. What I meant is e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96866 and then use `\alert<3->{...}` to change the color on some overlays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a lot of guess work and reading between the lines. It shows three ways (or two, depending on how you count) to change the color of something on some overlay. It would be much easier if you would consider posting a minimal (non)working example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{What is \texttt{\textbackslash alert} good for}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Just use  \texttt{\textbackslash alert} to colorize something on some
 overlay.
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 2\\ 
  0 & \alert<2>{1} & -1\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\] 
 \item You can change the alert color.
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 2\\ 
  0 & \alert<3>{1} & -1\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\] 
\item Or more brute force.
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 2\\ 
  0 & \alt<4>{\textcolor{magenta}{1}}{1} & -1\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\] 
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]